# How can I click a button if class changes every reload

Tags: javascript, html, button, click

Hello so I am using JavaScript and want to click a button. So my problem is that I can't find an id and the class_name of the button changes every time I reload the page so I also can't use

```
document.getElementByClassName("...").click()
```

So how can I click this button (picture)

[image: Button HTML]

Comment: If you can't edit the HTML to include a data attribute then you could use a different selector that relies on the structure of the HTML...

Comment: If it's always the `login_button` as in your image you can `document.querySelector("button[data-testid='login_button'])";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `data-testid` attribute along with tagName as parts of the selector

```
document.querySelector('button[data-testid="login_button"]').click()
```